# Prevent read Date from Excel file to convert to DateTime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I read Data from Excel table to my Application.
The Data can be a string, int double, Date, DateTime etc.

The thing is, in Excel the column contains the Date: `01.10.2014`
But if i import it to my application, it is an System.DateTime so it add time (from 01.01.2014 to 01/01/2013 12:00:00 AM) to it.

How can i prevent this? Or how can I say "if u are a DATE (not containing time) then be a System.Date" ?

Because im automaticly add the values to the DataBase i created a switch to get the DataTypes:

First, the Excel data will be stored in a DataTable. After this i loop it through a foreach to get the dataType and then I use a switch to convert the DateType to a MySQL Valid DataType name:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
   string dataType = "";
   switch(column.DataType.ToString())
   {
       case "System.DateTime":
           dataType = "DATETIME";
           break;
       case "System.Int32":
           dataType = "INT";
           break;
       case "System.Date":
           dataType = "DATE";
           break;
    }
}
```

and because it converts to DateTime, the value is completely different in MySQL.
For example:

```
In Excel: 01.01.2014
In Application: 01/01/2013 12:00:00 AM
In MySQL: 2001-01-20 14:00:00.000000
```

Why isn't it a Date if it is a Date ? I mean in my eyes `01.01.2014` is not a DateTIME.

Comment: There is no such a datatype as System.Date. You can convert DateTime to Date.

Comment: In the .NET Framework there is no type for 'Date without a Time-part'. `System.DateTime` always has a time component, which becomes 00:00:00 when it is not present in the source. As for MySQL, I have no knowledge but **[-here-](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)** it says that there is a **DATE** type, I suggest you try using that.

Comment: There isn't really a Date DataType for .NET ? o.O I always thought. And yes MySQL has a Date DataType. So I need to convert DateTime into Date I read this in another question how this convert will work. The thing is, how to check if a string is a DateTime ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Date in C# as a System Class. But, you can use the method ToShortDateString() to get the date part as a string. If mysql doesnt get it right there is surely a simple way to convert it.

Comment: Guess that will work. Only need to make the sql work now because getting SQL Error now while trying to insert 01.01.2014 to DATE.

Comment: `01/01/2013 12:00:00 AM` isn't `01/01/2013` with a time added to it. It's midnight - there is no time. That's how a date with no time is represented. If you have a `DateTime` and you only want the date with no time, use the `Date` property of a `DateTime` instance. It returns only the date with the time truncated. In other words, it returns the date at midnight.

Comment: But why it saves `2001-01-20 14:00:00.000000` to mysql ?
Nvm. Now it works if i save it in mysql format (yyyy-MM-dd). Now i got the midnight time as you said. I guess now I if I want to read mysql data I need to convert it back ToShortDateString() ?